# Гарантировать правдивость результатов голосования с помощью проверки IP адреса

Tags: php, javascript, проверка

Нужно провести интернет-голосование. Во избежание повторных голосов помимо некоторых проверок на стороне клиента я фиксирую на стороне сервера IP юзера и id голосования. Соответственно, если юзер с данным IP уже участвовал в голосовании с данным id, больше его голоса по данному опросу не принимаются. Но с другой стороны ведь ситуация, когда на 1 внешнем IP сидит куча человек, как я понимаю, достаточно распространенная у провайдеров особенно в крупных городах, и получится, что как только 1 из них проголосует, его соседи, сидящие на том же внешнем IP, уже проголосовать не смогут (если вдруг забредут). И вопрос - не является ли описанная выше проверка по IP слишком строгой и какова альтернатива на бэкэнде?

Возможно, практическое значение этих действий достаточно слабое, так как есть определенная вероятность, что не зачтутся некоторые голоса, но ими можно пренебречь, а теоретически меня напрягает ситуация, что если такую проверку по IP убрать, то выходит, что кто-то может у себя в браузере залезть в яваскрипт и послать 100500 тыщ запросов, значительно исказив результаты голосования. Получается выбор меньшего из двух зол. Как в итоге лучше сделать-то: оставить открытые ворота и надеяться, что всё будет ок или максимально застраховаться? Может я что-то упускаю.

Comment: Регистрация на сайте есть?

Comment: есть, но опрос предполагает более широкую аудиторию, чем зарегистрированные юзеры. К тому же, при необходимости я, как плохиш, могу и зарегиться, получив доступ к опросу.

Comment: Плохиш будет регистироваться ради каждого фейкового голоса?
Вы хотите и рыбку скушать и косточкой не подавиться, мне кажется.
Как еще один вариант - требовать для голосования ввода email и делать подтверждение голоса через него. Но при желании и здесь можно наплодить сущностей. Да и отпугнет это 80% потенциальных добропорядочных пользователей.

Comment: почему ради каждого? Сделал профиль, показался опрос. Опрос сделан на ajax и потом просто находишь место в коде, где идёт отправка голоса и ставишь эту отправку в цикл. Я сам так 1 раз в учебных целях одну голосовалку можно сказать хакнул, но потом написал организаторам о проблеме.

Comment: Но ведь при авторизации вы создаете на стороне клиента ту же куку.
Которую уже удалять не имеет смысла - её можно сделать уникальной для каждого пользователя и все.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Гарантировано защитить голосование в интернете способов нет, неплохо защитить голосование можно только по проверке уникального документа который выдается гражданину или уникального аккаунта в гос. сервисе который может быть подтвержден только по этому документу, хотя знайте, что документы можно подделать или украсть, а голос вашего пользователя можно купить на бирже задач, но это все зависит от цели и масштабов, которые преследует злоумышленник.

Я к чему веду, главное в вашем вопросе - это анализ и понимание, есть ли смысл вообще что-то придумывать, если голосование проходит просто по необходимости получить статистику.

**Помните**, цена защиты никогда не должна превышать той выгоды, который мошенник может получить с данной победы.

### Решения

1) Самое простое решение для Вас, это сделать интернет-опрос среди зарегистированных пользователей с ограничением по какому-то внутреннему параметру, например по дате регистрации или общему рейтингу. Например на **stackoverflow**, пользователь имеющий меньший рейтинг - имеет меньше возможностей. Это реализовано верно, ведь если потребуется накрутить голоса на сайте использующем подобный алгоритм, то цена этой накрутки будет вероятно больше среднестатистического приза, который можно получить и никто этим заниматься просто не будет. Под призом я понимаю все что угодно (материальный, нематериальный)

2) @VladD обозначил интересную идею с идентификацией через browser fingerprints, и это возможно с помощью библиотеки FingerprintJS, процент определения: 90% - это позволяет с помощью вычисления программно-аппаратных параметров, установки значений во всякие localStorage с большим успехом определить вас.

3) Пользователи легко обходят этот способ выключая Javascript и т.д. снижая тем самым уникальность отпечатка, но это легко обойти добавив к этому Google ReCaptcha, которая позволит избежать автоматических голосов.

4) Отправляйте СМС и регистрируйте телефонные номера - это дорого и не всегда эффективно.

5) Если у пользователя нет аккаунта в вашем сервисе, то позвольте проголосовать с помощью другого доверенного сервиса (не социальной сети!), по возможности запросите данные о дате регистрации в этом сервисе и другую информацию которая поможет его идентифицировать.

### Дополнительные меры

1) Не показывайте голоса - это введет злоумышленника в неведении текущей ситуации, а обычным пользователям знать не нужно о количестве голосов, пока оно проводится.

2) Есть возможность подменять варианты ответов или перемешивать их, это позволит сбить с толку людей, которым выдана задача проголосовать за вариант номер 4 :)

3) Голосование можно показывать выборочно (пачками), тут все зависит от вашей фантазии.

---

Используйте всего по чуть-чуть и получите более-менее верный алгоритм определения результатов.

**Количество голосов не главное, наиболее важно их качество.**

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - использовать файлы cookie на стороне клиента.
Создаете куку с идентификатором, а идентификатор сохраняете в базу.

Comment: Угу, поставить и надеяться что никто не умеет чистить куки.

Comment: @VladD, А как вы еще хотите? Сложная структура из совокупности всей доступной из браузера информации о клиенте типа версии браузера, ip и т.п.?

Comment: Да, нечто похожее уже есть, но если взять случай какого-нибудь плохиша - отключил/почистил куки и при проверке он будет как неголосовавший. Ясно, что к 99,9% юзеров это не относится и суть - в защите данных от возможного внешнего влияния.

Comment: @curveball, согласен, и с вами и с товарищем VladD, но действительно, процент таких людей чертовски мал.
Если хотите большей безопасности - вводите обязательную регистрацию для голосования.

Comment: @curveball, погуглите "browser fingerprints". Эта... технология может помочь. Правда против curl'а нет приёма.

Comment: @VladD ок, спасибо, звучит интересно.